# Question about notation regarding quantiles in standard normal distribution

Tags: statistics, notation, normal-distribution

If I have

$$\alpha  = \Pr(Z \leq c)$$

then then means

$$z_\alpha = c$$

where $z_\alpha$ is the $\alpha$ quantile of the $N(0,1)$ distribution right?

Answer (score 1):

Correct.  In R statistical software the CDF is denoted `pnorm` and its inverse,
the quantile function, is denoted 'qnorm`.

For example, let $\alpha = 0.05.$

```
c = qnorm(.05);  c
## -1.644854
pnorm(c)
## 0.05
```

In the figure below, the area under the normal density curve to the left
of the vertical red line (at $z = -1.645)$ is $0.05.$

[image]

Note: I don't know whether you are using software or printed tables of the
standard normal distribution. In most printed tables, you have to
look up positive z-values and get negative ones by symmetry. From
printed tables, you should be able to find that +1.645 cuts 5% of
the area from the *upper* (positive) tail of the standard normal distribution.